# Why doesn't my getMin function return the smallest value?

Tags: arrays, c, function, min, minimum

It seems my `getMin` function for an array of decimals isn't returning the actual minimum value.  I designed it to also ignore `-1`.  Any ideas? This is an example function of how I implemented `getMin` on a larger project. The best it returns is `0.01`

```
#include <stdio.h>

float getMin(float arr[10]) {
    int i = 0;
    float min;
    //find first non-negative value
    for (i; i < 10; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != -1) {
            min = arr[i];
            goto done;
        }
    }
  done:
    for (i; i < 10 - i - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < min && arr[i] != -1) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int main() {
    float array[10] = { -1, -1, .03, .02, .01, -1, .05, .001, 5, 0.0125 };
    printf("Hello World");
    float min = getMin(array);
    printf("min: %f\n", min);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i; i<10-i; i++)` - why aren't you going to the end of the array?

Comment: Oh, I miswrote the code. The one in the project uses for(i; i<10-i-1; i++), which still doesn't give me the smallest value.  My understanding is that the second for loop starts from the first non-negative number and I should run the loop until then to avoid attempting to access data beyond the array.

Comment: The last element in the array is ` i == 9`. It is a constant. It doesn't matter where you started.

Comment: but shouldn't it still display .001 as the smallest value?

Comment: What is the expected output? Smallest positive number? Or the smallest number overall?

Comment: The expected output is the smallest positive number.

Comment: Run it with a debugger and step through the second loop in `getMin()`. Check how many times it iterates, what the value of `i`, `arr[i]`, etc. is at every iteration. This is how you debug such a problem. We could do it for you, but then you'd learn nothing.

Comment: Ah, I fixed it I believe. Thank you.

Comment: Your second loop stops when i is 5. 5 <10-5-1.

Comment: What happens if there is no positive number ? No need for 2 loops. goto statement,even if possible, should never be used.

Comment: You can simply initialize `min` to -1 (`float min = -1;`) and then search for positive value. And it is better to use `double` instead of `float`.

Comment: @i486 if you initialize `min` to `-1` how do you compare it with `arr[i]` later?

Comment: @Bob__ `if ( min < 0 || ( min > arr[i] && arr[i] >= 0 ) ) min = arr[i];`. I don't see the need of 2 loops for such simple task.

Comment: @i486 Well, the not-so-simple task is how to deal with those pesky corner cases, like passing an empty (0-sized or NULL pointer) array or an array *without* positive numbers, but yes, you can use a single loop, of course. I just would have chosen a different starting [value](https://godbolt.org/z/sMTn7xnn4).

Answer (score -1):

The loop test `i < 10 - i - 1` is incorrect. There is a confusion between the index number and the number of elements left to test. You should just test if `i < 10`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float getMin(const float arr[10], size_t len) {
    size_t i;
    float min;

    //find first non-negative value
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= 0)
            break;
    }
    if (i == len) {
        // all values are negative
        return 0;
    }
    min = arr[i];
    for (i++; i < len; i++) {
        if (arr[i] >= 0 && arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int main() {
    float array[10] = { -1, -1, .03, .02, .01, -1, .05, .001, 5, 0.0125 };
    printf("Hello World\n");
    float min = getMin(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));
    printf("min: %f\n", min);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World
min: 0.001000
```